How to change the progress bar background color in Bulma?
I'm using Bulma CSS.
My whole page has white background color but there is a problem with the progress bar:

the black isn't needed.
I've tried this:
.progress-bar-custom {
  --bulma-progress-bar-background-color: white;
}
.progress-bar-custom-bg {
  --bulma-progress-value-background-color: white;
}

but it doesn't help me.
Here is my progress bar code:
<div style="position: relative; width: 100%;">
    <progress class="progress is-danger progress-bar-custom progress-bar-custom-bg" value="90" max="90">
        90%
    </progress>
    <button class="button is-danger is-rounded" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 10%;" onclick="alert('Нажата кнопка 1')">Кнопка 1</button>
    <button class="button is-primary is-rounded" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 30%;" onclick="alert('Нажата кнопка 2')">Кнопка 2</button>
    <button class="button is-primary is-rounded" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;" onclick="alert('Нажата кнопка 3')">Кнопка 3</button>
    <button class="button is-primary is-rounded" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 70%;" onclick="alert('Нажата кнопка 4')">Кнопка 4</button>
</div>

How can I change this black background?

If you'd rather get answers, add a snippet here,but time is running out against you: other questions will compete with yours.
